# How to get unique random items from an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, random

Hey there,
I have an array of (unique) objects and would like to get 4 random objects of this array, but the same object shouldn't be fetched twice, so using a simple random function won't work.

I had two ideas:
1. Shuffle the array and get the first 4 items. -> Overhead, because the array can be very large.
2. Generate a random index. If that index was used before, try again, and so on... -> Somewhat unreliable...

Do you know a better, more efficient method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Shuffle the array and get the first 4 items. -> Overhead, because the array can be very large.

Use the [modern version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Modern_method) of the [Fisher Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It can be performed [in-place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm) and if you stop after the first four swaps it will give you the result you need. There is no need to shuffle the entire array.

> Compared to some other solutions, it also has the advantage that, if only part of the resulting permutation is needed, it can be stopped halfway through

Comment: Is there ever a "get unique random items from an array" where Fisher-Yates is *not* applicable? :-/

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. And pretty simple, too. :)

Comment: You link a Wikipedia page of a guy. How does this answer the question? You may as well link any person BIO who did a bit of math.