# Get two different random items from same array in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking to get two different random items from the same array in JS. There are relating questions on Stack Overflow but I fail to understand how the [Fisher Yates Shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053480/how-to-get-unique-random-items-from-an-array) works. I need to search the whole array to retrieve these items, but the array is small in size.

Currently I have a while loop but this doesn't seem to be the most efficient way of acheiving:

```
    var honeyPots = ["Fname", "EmailAddress", "Lname", "Telephone", "Address1", "Address2", "Surname", "Title"]; //Fake field names to dupe the bots!
    var honeyPot = honeyPots[Math.floor(Math.random()*honeyPots.length)]; //Get a random field name from the array
    var honeyPot2 = honeyPots[Math.floor(Math.random()*honeyPots.length)]; //Get a random field name from the array
    while (honeyPot == honeyPot2)
      {
        var honeyPot2 = honeyPots[Math.floor(Math.random()*honeyPots.length)];
      }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just shuffle the array and get first two items:

```
var honeyPots = ["Fname", "EmailAddress", "Lname", "Telephone", "Address1", "Address2", "Surname", "Title"];

var results = honeyPots
    .sort(function() { return .5 - Math.random() }) // Shuffle array
    .slice(0, 2); // Get first 2 items

var honeyPot = results[0];
var honeyPot2 = results[1];
```

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, is that sort function a similar concept to that which the Fisher Yates Shuffle defines?

Comment: No, it's another approach.

Comment: There is an excellent article with visualizations of array sort methods here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/ Assuming I've set it up correctly, the final method on that page performs better than the one in this answer: http://jsben.ch/wotnS. Not a consideration in most cases, probably, and the one here succinct!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like,

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,4,5,8];
var randomValue = [];
for(i=arr.length; i>=0; i--) {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * i);
  randomValue.push(arr[randomNum]);
  if(i==arr.length-1)break;
}
console.log(randomValue);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @alexey-prokhorov's answer but using a [different method](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/) for shuffling the array, you could do something like:

```
var getRandosFromArray = function(array, numRandos){
  var shuffled = shuffle(array)
  var randos = shuffled.slice(0, numRandos)
  return randos
}

// https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
var shuffle = function(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

  return array;
}
```

That way you have a generic function to which you can just pass an array and the number of random items (which are returned in an array) you want back from it.